# Make a nicer looking dropdown filter label with DataTables DT in R

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I'm trying to make a datatable for a shiny dashboard that will have a dropdown filter on a column. I actually have it working, but the appearance is what I'd call subpar.

Here is my simple example

```
library(DT)
mytable <- data.frame(Col1 = as.factor(LETTERS[1:3]))
datatable(mytable, filter = "top")
```

When I have the dropdown active, the filter text input looks nice:

[image]

However, when I click away, it does not look as nice:

[image]

Is there any way to keep that nice looking A with an x in a bubble (sorry I'm sure there's a better term for that), or at least get rid of the bracket and quotation marks? I know that if the column values are characters rather than factors, I can get a nicer looking text input, but them I lose the dropdown functionality (related to this question [Factor dropdown filter in DT::datatable in shiny dashboards not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168646/factor-dropdown-filter-in-dtdatatable-in-shiny-dashboards-not-working)), which I need.

```
mytable <- data.frame(Col1 = LETTERS[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
datatable(mytable, filter = "top")
```

[image]

I'd be happy with a cell dropdown like the one in this post [Edit datatable in Shiny with dropdown selection for factor variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593539/edit-datatable-in-shiny-with-dropdown-selection-for-factor-variables), but I need to filter the table, not edit it.

Version info:

R version 3.5.3

DT_0.20

Answer (score 5):

I know how to do that but with the dropdowns in the footer, I don't know how to put them at the top. The code uses the JavaScript library **select2**.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- iris

sketch <- htmltools::tags$table(
  tableHeader(c("",names(dat))),
  tableFooter(rep("", 1+ncol(dat)))
)

js <- c(
  "function(){", 
  "  this.api().columns().every(function(i){",
  "    var column = this;",
  "    var select = $('<select multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"\"></option></select>')",
  "      .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )", 
  "      .on('change', function(){",
  "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index,element){",
  "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
  "        }).toArray().join('|');",
  "        column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false).draw();",
  "      });",
  "    var data = column.data();",
  "    if(i == 0){",
  "      data.each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }else{",
  "      data.unique().sort().each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }",
  "    select.select2({width: '100%', closeOnSelect: false});",
  "  });",
  "}")


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, container=sketch, 
      options = list(
        initComplete = JS(js),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## Edit

To have the filters at the top:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

dat <- iris

sketch <- tags$table(
  tags$thead(
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(),
      lapply(names(dat), tags$th)
    ),
    tags$tr(
      tags$th(id = "th0"),
      tags$th(id = "th1"),
      tags$th(id = "th2"),
      tags$th(id = "th3"),
      tags$th(id = "th4"),
      tags$th(id = "th5")
    )
  )
)

js <- c(
  "function(){", 
  "  this.api().columns().every(function(i){",
  "    var column = this;",
  "    var select = $('<select multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"\"></option></select>')",
  "      .appendTo( $('#th'+i).empty() )", 
  "      .on('change', function(){",
  "        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index,element){",
  "          return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());",
  "        }).toArray().join('|');",
  "        column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false).draw();",
  "      });",
  "    var data = column.data();",
  "    if(i == 0){",
  "      data.each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }else{",
  "      data.unique().sort().each(function(d, j){",
  "        select.append('<option value=\"'+d+'\">'+d+'</option>');",
  "      });",
  "    }",
  "    select.select2({width: '100%', closeOnSelect: false});",
  "  });",
  "}")


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js")
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, container=sketch, 
      options = list(
        orderCellsTop = TRUE,
        initComplete = JS(js),
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center")
        )
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That does look nicer. For my UI though, I need the filter inputs to be above the table, and also for some of the column filters I need to be able to filter by typed text rather than a dropdown/select

Comment: @Andreas Please look at my edit. You are not obliged to select a predefined option, you can type text in the box as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. That's even closer. About being able to filter by typed text, I mean, for your example, I'd like to be able to type "v" under species and for the table to filter for rows with "v" (that would be versicolor and virginica in this example)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I would like to limit the drop down search to only a few columns, but still have the normal data table filter by text for the others. Could you advise?

Comment: Unfortunately, the query builds the drop down based off of the visualized table. Meaning if you have 10 rows visible out of 1000, you only get dropdown values of the 10 shown. Any unique values in the remaining 990 are absent.

Comment: @Ghoti Not true... look at the Species column in the GIF.

Comment: Aaah I think it's a limitation of server side vs client side data table construction.