# DT::renderDataTable filter does not work when data is dynamically updated

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm attempting to dynamically update the contents of a data frame using a radio toggle. For use case, think changing the language of data in the table between English and Spanish. I've found that when data is dynamically updated, filters aren't built. The only halfway decent solutions I've come up with:

1. build the filter functionality using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035860/make-a-nicer-looking-dropdown-filter-label-with-datatables-dt-in-r/71050139?noredirect=1#comment136686733_71050139) as reference. Requires client side processing, which isn't ideal (fairly large dataset).
2. build multiple separate tables and selectively toggle visibility so that only the current active table is shown (untested, but seems possible albeit impractical).

Perhaps there's a better solution? I'm open to suggestions. Below is a minimum reproducible example of the filter functionality breaking when data changes. Note that all columns in column_list are dynamically altered ("X" appended) and filter no longer works in those columns.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

d <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  d_col_rct <- reactive({
    sub_regex = "X$|$"
    column_list <- list("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Species")
    for(column in column_list) {
      d[[column]] <- sub(sub_regex, "X", d[[column]], perl=TRUE)
      if(is.factor(d[[column]])) {
        d[[column]] <- droplevels(d[[column]]) 
      }
    }
    d
  })

  output[["dtable"]] <- DT::renderDataTable(
    {
      d_col_rct()
    },
    filter="top",
    rownames=FALSE,
    style="bootstrap",
    selection=list(
      mode="single",
      target="column",
      selected=0
    ),
    extensions = c("ColReorder"),
    options = list(
      dom = 'Blfrtip',
      autoWidth=FALSE,
      orderMulti=TRUE,
      searching=TRUE,
      search.regex=TRUE,
      lengthMenu=list(c(10,25,50,100,100), c('10','25', '50', '100', '1000')),
      pageLength=25
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns must be `factor` in order to have the filters:

```r
  d_col_rct <- reactive({
    sub_regex = "X$|$"
    column_list <- list("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Species")
    for(column in column_list) {
      d[[column]] <- sub(sub_regex, "X", d[[column]], perl=TRUE)
      d[[column]] <- as.factor(d[[column]]) 
    }
    d
  })
```